# Tool for pixel and vertex shader

Tags: xna, shader, pixel-shader, vertex-shader

Is there any tool for testing pixel and vertex shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**nVidia FX Composer**](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/fx_composer_home.html) (There was also AMD (formerly ATI) [RenderMonkey](http://developer.amd.com/archive/gpu/rendermonkey/pages/default.aspx), but it looks like that's been shelved.)

Finally, you may find [**PIX**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417062(VS.85).aspx) useful for testing shaders as they are used in your application. It is included in the DirectX SDK.

Answer (score 1):

For HLSL Effects that you can use in XNA (PS 2.0-3.0) you can try:

<s>[3DPee (Tridipy) player and shader editor](http://marino.boletus.hr/)</s> *(dead link)*

It operates on images and video.
It supports multi pass technique, vertext shader, and has a nice editor with error message reporting on compile.
It's an alpha version i have developed but it can be useful.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Mac to use it, but Apple's [OpenGL Shader Builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLShaderBuilderUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is pretty nice. You can literally type in shaders and run them live, outside of your application.

Answer (score 0):

A nice one here for WebGL: http://glsl.heroku.com